Windows display scaling at 125% breaks map center position
We have a pretty simple mini-map component in Angular, which initializes an OSM layer, a vector layer for entity display and that's pretty much it. Provided entity is displayed on the map with SVG icon.
It works fine in all broswers, both Windows and Mac, but when user has Windows Display Scaling set to 125% or 175% it somehow automatically pans the map view to Atlantic Ocean. Oddly enough, not to [0,0]. Zooming out or panning to the entity location shows its icon at the correct coordinates.
Code is really simple, basically just this:
constructor() {
  this.osmLayer = new TileLayer({
    opacity: 1,
    source: new OSM()
  });
  this.locationLayer = new VectorLayer({
    source: new VectorSource({
      features: [],
      format: new GeoJSON()
    })
  });
}

initMap(): void {
  const zoomControl = new Zoom({
    delta: 0.5
  });

  this.map = new Map({
    layers: [this.osmLayer, this.locationLayer],
    target: 'locationMap',
    view: new View({
      // const DEFAULT_CENTER_COORDINATE: Coordinate = [16.5, 48.2];
      center: fromLonLat(DEFAULT_CENTER_COORDINATE),
      zoom: 14
    }),
    controls: [zoomControl]
  });

  this.map.once('postrender', () => {
    const view = this.map.getView();
    // this.centerCoordinates - provided in location object @Input()
    view.setCenter(this.centerCoordinates);
    // this.locationType - string, provided via @Input()
    this.createFeature(this.locationType);
  });
}

private createFeature(locationType: string): void {
  const geometry = new Point(this.centerCoordinates);
  const locationFeature = new Feature<Geometry>({ geometry });

  // loadIconStyle - loads location icon SVG from assets folder
  const iconStyle = this.loadIconStyle(locationType);
  locationFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);

  const source = this.locationLayer.getSource();
  if (source) {
    source.addFeature(locationFeature);
  }
}

Do you have any idea what exactly is causing this and how can we handle this issue? We are using Tailwind CSS in our project and the resolution for the map component div is set using REM values. So I guess this is not the issue. Since the mini map component allows basic interactions I'd like to avoid some on/once callbacks for this.

It's impossible to say what's going on without complete reproducible sample to try online (JSFiddle, CodePen ...).

I'm aware of that, I'll try to reproduce it and I'll provide stackblitz.
